# Wordpress. Getting logo to be in front of menu or header

Tags: php, css, wordpress, themes

I am using the Avada theme and cannot figure out how to get the logo in front of the menu or header. It looks like the logo is part of the wrapper that contains the header, menu and logo. So if I change one, it affects the other.

This is how the theme has the logo set up -

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXnLT.jpg

This is the desired style -

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ocLgV.jpg

Thank you if anyone can help. :3

Comment: Both are the same image?

Comment: So what are the concrete CSS and HTML snippets, or attempts to rewrite things. Screenshots alone rarely make a useful programming question. (Btw, plastering posts with "help" doesn't really help any future users.)

Comment: @ManojKumar Oh, sorry. I corrected the link.

Comment: @mario i don't know if this helps or not, but I took a screenshot of what should be the html and css that I need to edit; but everything I have tried does not work. Apologies for the title. This is literally my first time posting on here for help, so not all familiar yet with the etiquette - https://imgur.com/PbbBIWn

Comment: It is difficult for others to help without you posting the code you have tried :(

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't this be associated to z-index? As in, apply a z-index value to the navigation div the logo is sitting on and apply another z-index attribute with a higher value to the logo div? I think as long as the logo is position:absolute, position:relative, or position:fixed you should be good.

Here:
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp